# Return reference to an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing, url, reference

First off, let me tell you that I have worked very little with Arrays and never with Hashes. Also, Perl is not my strongest scripting language.  I come from a background in shell scripting.

That said, I have this in a Perl script:

```
$monitored_paths = { '/svn/test-repo'  => 'http://....list.txt' };
```

The URL points to a file which contains a list of paths like this:

```
/src/cpp
/src/test
/src/test2
```

The objective is to replace the URL with the contents:

```
$monitored_paths = {'svn/test-repo' => '/src/cpp', '/src/test', '/src/test2'}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?   Thanks!

Sam

Comment: A hash it just an array indexed using a string instead of a number.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the premise of your question, because this line:

```
$monitored_paths = {'svn/test-repo' => '/src/cpp', '/src/test', '/src/test2'}
```

is the equivalent of either of these:

```
$monitored_paths = {'svn/test-repo' => '/src/cpp', '/src/test' => '/src/test2'}
$monitored_paths = {'svn/test-repo', '/src/cpp', '/src/test', '/src/test2'}
```

What you really want is:

```
$monitored_paths = {'svn/test-repo' => ['/src/cpp', '/src/test', '/src/test2']}
```

where [] denotes an array reference. You create an array reference like this:

```
my $arrayref = [1, 2, 3]; # called an "anonymous array reference"
```

or like this:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3);
my $arrayref = \@array;
```

You want something such as:

```
$monitored_paths = { '/svn/test-repo'  => 'http://....list.txt' }
foreach my $key (keys %$monitored_paths) {
    next if ref $monitored_paths{$key} eq 'ARRAY'; # skip if done already
    my @paths = get_paths_from_url($key);
    $monitored_paths->{$key} = \@paths; # replace URL with arrayref of paths
}
```

replacing get_paths_from_url with your URL-fetching and parsing function (using LWP or whatever...since that was not really part of your question I assume you already know how to do that). If you write your function get_paths_from_url to return an array reference in the first place instead of an array, you can save a step and write `$monitored_paths->{$key} = get_paths_from_url($key)` instead.

Comment: Excellent!  Yes, I agree I did not present my question correctly.  Sorry about that.  Yes, I already figured out to LWP to fetch contents from the URL.  I'll give your code a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: No need to apologize, just describing the proper syntax. If it works, accept an answer please.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to get it to work.  The $monitored_paths is a mix of regular paths and URL's.  So, running this over all the items using the foreach needs to be avoided. I need to put a "if ref..." after the foreach but can't quite get the syntax to check.  Also, how can I print the contents of $monitored_paths in the end assuming everything went well?  In the get_paths_from_url function, when I print content of $ARGV[0], I get /svn/test-repo a bunch of times on the screen.  It should ideally be the URL.  :(

Comment: Lots of questions... 1. I don't know what you want to do when it's not a URL then. Skip it with `next if $monitored_paths{$key} =~m/^http/;`  2. You can "print the contents" with `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($monitored_paths);`  3. @ARGV is for command line arguments, subroutine arguments are passed into @_ (so first argument is $_[0], second is $_[1]). Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I can use the match substring http I think. That should work.  I'll give it a shot first thing tomorrow.  If there is no http:, then we just skip it.  I'll also try the Data::Dumper like you suggested.  I tried using it in various other ways with no success.  Thanks again! :)

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

    use Data::Dumper;
    use LWP::Simple;

    $monitored_paths = {
    '/svn/test_promote' => [ 'trunk/web/javascript' ,     'branches/prd_gold/web' ],
'/svn/some-repo' =>  'http://svn/svn/services/trunk/om/services/om_current_nouns.txt'
};

    print "Value of monitored paths is\n";
    print Dumper($monitored_paths);

    print "value of key is\n";
    foreach my $key (keys %$monitored_paths) {
     print "$key\n";
     #print $monitored_paths{$key};
    }

Comment: That script gives the output:Value of monitored paths is
$VAR1 = {
          '/svn/some-repo' => 'http://svn/svn/services/trunk/om/services/om_current_nouns.txt',
          '/svn/test_promote' => [
                                   'trunk/web/javascript',
                                   'branches/prd_gold/web'
                                 ]
        };
value of key is
/svn/some-repo
/svn/test_promote

Comment: And if I use  print $monitored_paths{$key}; it comes back empty.  So, when I try to look for http as in $monitored_paths{$key} =~m/^http/; it does not match.  I can now print the key values, how can I print the values in the hash?  I mean the /branches/prd_gold, etc.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in the code, which is partially my fault (please `use strict` and `use warnings`). Use `$monitored_paths->{$key}` -- since $monitored_path is a hash *reference*, you need the arrow operator to dereference it.

Comment: Yeah the arrow operator works!  Thank you!  I'll get back with the result.  :)

Comment: Its working!  Thanks.  Here are the details            `foreach my $key (keys %$monitored_paths){
  if ($monitored_paths->{$key} =~ /^http/) {
    $monitored_paths->{$key} = &get_paths_from_url($monitored_paths->{$key}); # Call subroutine get_paths_from_url
  }
}
`                                                                     Sub: `$URL = $_[0] ;  return \@arr;`

Answer (score 0):

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $content = get($url); ## do some error checking
$monitored_paths = {'svn/test-repo' => [split( "\n", $content)]}
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.  I cannot hard-code the paths.  They have to reside in the URL and have to be read during runtime.

Comment: Lookup URL using the original hash and perform a get on those URLs and create a new hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from the file and add each path to the array you could
do something like:

```
use strictures 1;

my $monitored_paths = {};
open( my $FILE, '<', '/path/to/file' ) or die 'Unable to open file '. $!;
while($FILE){
    push @{ $monitored_paths->{'svn/test-repo'} }, $_;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Actually, the monitored_paths, in addition to the URL has a bunch of other references as well.  Can I just add your code to stack on top of it?

Comment: Sure. If you dump the monitored_paths variables you'll see the 'svn/test-repo' and the routes.  If you need more keys just push them on to different keys depending on a condition.  print Dumper($monitored_paths);

Comment: That won't work because they value of `$monitored_paths->{'svn/test-repo'}` is not an array reference yet, you cannot push on it. You can add a check using ref() before the push, and set it to [] if ref() is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
use LWP;
foreach (keys %monitored_paths)
{
   my  $content = get($monitored_paths{$_});# Perform error checking
   $monitored_paths_final {$_} = join(",",split("\n",$content));
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in that code, it creates a new hashref and assigns it to $monitored_paths_final each time. You will end up with only one key in it (the last one in the loop).